# How to format cell based on row of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that is used to track hours. I am trying to change the color of the cell that has hours greater than 0 but only for those hours less than today's date based on their column.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

What I am trying to get it to do is to look like this, as the date changes each day the hours behind it are grayed out.

[image]

I can't get the conditional format formula to work. I have tried

`=AND($F$25:$JB$25>0,$F$23:$JB$23<TODAY())`

`=IF($F$23:$JB$23<TODAY(),"",$F$25:$JB$32>0)`

`=AND($F$25:$JB$25>0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))<TODAY())`

Where row 23 is where the dates are and 25-32 are the hours

Any ideas? I'd like to do this without a macro if possible

Comment: `=AND(F25>0,F$23<TODAY())` And the applies to would be `$F$25:$JB$25`

Comment: Wow was it really that easy? I just add them to each row and it worked. I don't understand how it knows to look through row 23....i guess it just looks at the entire row and correlates it the cell column?